# What are the other named container of TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

After reading the paper of TensorFlow, I found that "There is a default container that persists until the process terminates. Other named containers may be initialized." or you can refer to https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-white-paper-notes#47-containers .

So what are the other named container? Can we store the Variable in persistent distributed storage, like database or NoSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the abstraction may support this in the future, but there are no other named containers available at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It's great to know about this from official developers. It helps a lot.